# winapi: from HDC to an HBITMAP

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi

I would like to do something which I believe is fairly simple but since I am new to the winapi I am finding a lot of problems. Basically I have an HDC (which I am BitBlitting from a loaded Bitmap) and I am drawing a rectangle on it. Then I would like to BitBlt that HDC onto a new HBITMAP Object, but alas for now to no avail.

Here is my code which I have been trying to get to work for a couple of hours now

```
BITMAPINFO info;
Bitmap *tempbmp = Bitmap::FromFile(L"C:\\Users\\abelajc\\Pictures\\BackgroundImage.png", false);
HBITMAP loadedbackground;
tempbmp->GetHBITMAP(NULL, &loadedbackground);

HBRUSH hRed = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));

HDC pDC = GetDC(0);
HDC TmpDC = CreateCompatibleDC(pDC); //main DC on which we will paint on

HDC dcBmp = CreateCompatibleDC(TmpDC); //DC for the loadedbackground HBitmap
HGDIOBJ TmpObj2 = SelectObject(dcBmp , tempbmp); //Selecting Bitmap in DC
BitBlt(TmpDC, 0, 0, 512, 512, dcBmp, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(dcBmp, TmpObj2); //Deselecting Bitmap from DC
DeleteDC(dcBmp);

RECT rectangle;
SetRect(&rectangle, 5, 5, 20, 20);
FillRect(TmpDC, &rectangle, hRed);

HDC hCompDC = CreateCompatibleDC(TmpDC);
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(TmpDC, 512, 512);
HBITMAP hOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hCompDC, hBmp);
BitBlt(hCompDC, 0, 0, 512, 512, TmpDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(hCompDC, hOld);
DeleteDC(hCompDC);

Bitmap *image = new Bitmap(hBmp, NULL);
```

Comment: You don't appear to perform any error checking at all. Perhaps one of your API calls is failing. That's winapi 101.

Comment: Do not `CreateCompatibleDC()` with memory DC. I remember that I had some troubles with doing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need some clarification about GDI.
A DC is exactly what its name imply : a device context. It's just a context, nothing concrete. Some DCs are context to a real graphic device, some others (memory DCs) are context to a virtual graphic surface in memory. The DCs you create with `CreateCompatibleDC` are memory DC, but creating the DC only create the context, not the memory surface. As the MSDN documentation says :

> Before an application can use a memory DC for drawing operations, it must select a bitmap of the correct width and height into the DC.

You need to associate a HBITMAP with the DC. After doing that, you can consider that drawing to the DC is essentially drawing to the bitmap. The memory DC is the 'window' to the bitmap.

Once you understand that, you will see that your program can be greatly shortened. Feel free to comment if you still have problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot with this explanation, I feel that with it I have understood one of the crucial parts in drawing using winapi which I was struggling with. I also managed to fix my code using what I learnt from this explanation :)

Comment: @JeanClaudeAbela You're welcome :) This part of GDI is indeed a bit obscure. I also had trouble in the past figuring how it really works.